# How to deal with missing data in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, missing-data

I have been looking for an answer to my question here stackExchange and by googling, but although some have had similar questions, I am not sure, I have found the right answer.

I am running a logistic regression in which I am analyzing the probability of a child being placed in foster care. Some of my independent variables are related to the childs parents - for example income and education. However, for some of the children a mother or a father is not present, and I therefore don't know their income, education etc. My question is, should I code the income for a missing parent to be zero or should I just leave it blank? I should note that for both the  mother and the father, I have already created a binary variable that tells if the parent is unknown.

If I leave the income for a missing father blank, does that mean, that the child with the missing father and missing income, isn't a part of my regression?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, should I code the income for a missing parent to be zero or should I just leave it blank?

If the data is missing because there is no information on that parent's income, then imputing the missing data with 0s creates a bias.  The reality is that the parents likely made *some* money.

You could either: Drop variables with missing information or use an imputation method (maybe MICE or something else).  If you choose this route, I would research what the typical method of comparing regressions with and without imputation is.